# Aggregate multiple rows between two numbers

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate

Let's say we have this table:
table1

| sensor_id | start_time_index | end_time_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

And another table with:
table2

| sensor_id | time_index | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'A' |
| 1 | 2 | 'B' |
| 1 | 3 | 'A' |
| 1 | 4 | 'C' |
| 1 | 5 | 'D' |
| 1 | 6 | 'B' |
| 2 | 1 | 'B' |
| 2 | 2 | 'C' |
| 2 | 3 | 'D' |
| 2 | 4 | 'A' |

Desired table is:

| sensor_id | start_time_index | end_time_index | values_concatenated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | "ABAC" |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | "BACDB" |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | "BCD" |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | "CDA" |

I didn't know how to aggregate between a range that's specified between two values that are in two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "range join" `ON col BETWEEN ...  AND ...` and `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT tab1.sensor_id, tab1.start_time_index, tab1.end_time_index,
  LISTAGG(tab2.value) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY tab2.time_index) AS values_contatenated
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2
  ON tab1.sensor_id = tab2.sensor_id
 AND tab2.time_index BETWEEN tab1.start_time_index AND tab1.end_time_index
GROUP BY tab1.sensor_id, tab1.start_time_index, tab1.end_time_index
```

Comment: Typo: `BETWEEN tab1.start_time_index = tab1.end_time_index`